# Wiktionary for dictd - where to obtain?

Tags: dictionary, dict

I have `dictd` installed and some dictionaries. I'd like to add Wiktionary but websearch does not find it, only bilinguals based on it. Any idea how/where to obtain one? Maybe make into `dict` format from other?

Comment: https://www.dictinfo.com/

Comment: @Devon, thanks, the link does contain some dictionaries. There is however a difference from online one (as displayed in foliate ebook reader) - no hyperlinks (and generally far worse formatting). I've tried `dictd format, English Wiktionary, English language only, v.2023-Feb-19`

Comment: I think now that `dict` does not support hyperlinks; the app itself supported it for online wiki one.